# How do I update a cloned HTML canvas element with the context and data of the original canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have written a script that allows users to draw simple lines on top of an html 5 canvas element. The ultimate goal is to have this drawing being tiled and repeated across the rest of the browser. I have gotten a cloned canvas onto the page but am struggling on how to draw the same lines simultaneously on top of multiple canvases.

I will paste my code below

```
var size = 40;
var md = false;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', down);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', toggledraw);

canvas.width  = 600;
canvas.height = 600;

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', move);

function move(evt){

  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  var posx = mousePos.x;
  var posy = mousePos.y;
  draw(canvas, posx, posy);

  window.posx;


  return mousePos;



};


function down(){
  md = true;
}

function toggledraw(){
  md = false;
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt){
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return{
    x:evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y:evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
};

function draw(canvas, posx, posy){
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


  if(md){
    context.fillRect(posx, posy, size, size)
  }

};

cloneCanvas(canvas, window.posx, window.posy, size);

function cloneCanvas(canvas, posx, posy, size,) {
  console.log(posx);


  var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
  newCanvas.className = "newNew";


  newCanvas.width = canvas.width;
  newCanvas.height = canvas.height;
  document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);



  //context.fillRect(posx, posy, size, size)
  context.drawImage(canvas, posx, posy);



  return canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would go about it is to update the cloned canvas after drawing on the main canvas.

Based on your current code I would first want to return the cloned canvas instead of the old canvas. This way you have a reference to it.

```
 function cloneCanvas(canvas, posx, posy, size,) {
   ...
 //  --> return canvas;
 return newCanvas // Becomes this.
}
```

Next, looking at the line:

```
cloneCanvas(canvas, window.posx, window.posy, size);
```

I see that you're using your own "posx" and "posy" variables. I would get rid of those since you will always want to copy the whole canvas. (In this case). Change the line like this

```
var clone = cloneCanvas(canvas, 0, 0, size);
```

Next, I wrote a little helper function to link two canvases.

```
function drawFromSource(source, destination) {
  return function() {
    var context = destination.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, destination.width, destination.height);
    context.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

This function returns a callback that when called draws the the orginal canvas onto a cloned canvas.

You initialize it like this:

```
var updateClone = drawFromSource(canvas, clone);
```

And last but not least you have to add the newly created callback into the draw function. Right after you draw onto your main canvas.

```
function draw(canvas, posx, posy) {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (md) {
    context.fillRect(posx, posy, size, size)
    updateClone();
  }

};
```

Voila!
Here is a link to the working code, I shifted some of your code around.

https://jsfiddle.net/30efdvz3/5/

Just for fun. Tiled version just change "numberofTiles"

https://jsfiddle.net/30efdvz3/3/

Comment: Yes drawImage is the way to go, just one note though, you will want to [clear your clones](https://jsfiddle.net/30efdvz3/4/) before redrawing the updated canvas over it.

Comment: @Kaiido I added two lines to clear the clones before redrawing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

In this I have created a function for registering mouse event according to canvas. and call this function for all canvases.

```
var size = 40;
var md = false;
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas');
registerEvents(canvas1)
function move(evt){
    console.log(evt.target.id);
    var canvas = document.getElementById(evt.target.id);
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var posx = mousePos.x;
    var posy = mousePos.y;
    draw(canvas, posx, posy);
    window.posx;
    return mousePos;
};

function registerEvents(canvas){
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', down);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', toggledraw);
    canvas.width  = 600;
    canvas.height = 600;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
}
function down(){
    md = true;
}

function toggledraw(){
    md = false;
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt){
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return{
        x:evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y:evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
};

function draw(canvas, posx, posy){
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if(md){
        context.fillRect(posx, posy, size, size)
    }
};
cloneCanvas(canvas, window.posx, window.posy, size);
function cloneCanvas(canvas, posx, posy, size,) {
    console.log(posx);
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var id = "newCanvas";
    newCanvas.className = "newNew";
    newCanvas.id = id;
    newCanvas.width = canvas.width;
    newCanvas.height = canvas.height;
    newCanvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
    document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
    context.drawImage(canvas, posx, posy);
    registerEvents(document.getElementById(id))
    return canvas;
}
```

[Here is working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gzywehe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you were close, I have made just some changes and achieved what you desired, here is the [result](https://jsfiddle.net/4z49wu76/2/).

```
function cloneCanvas(canvas, posx, posy, size,) {
  var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
  ...
  return context; // this should return the context!
}
```

And,

```
var clonedCanvas = cloneCanvas(canvas, window.posx, window.posy, size);
// after you call the function get the 2d context to variable.
```

Last change is,

```
function draw(canvas, posx, posy){
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if(md){
  clonedCanvas.fillRect(posx, posy, size, size); // fillRect to variable that you defined at above,
    context.fillRect(posx, posy, size, size)
  }
};
```

**Jsfiddle output;**
[image]

Hope helps,